# cannot resolve state angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, ui-sref

I'm getting an error when trying to go from one state in my app to another one.

I have in an index file all my states defined.

index.js

```
var MyModule = angular.module('myApp.ui.moduleTest', [
  'ui.router'
])
.config(function($stateProvider, modalStateProvider){
  $stateProvider

    .state('myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest',
      modalStateProvider.create({
        animation: true,
        name: 'myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest',
        url: 'apps/moduleTest',
        controllerAs: 'moduleTestCtrl',
        controller: 'ModuleTestCtrl',
        windowClass: 'semi-modal semi-modal--huge',
        templateUrl: function() {
          return 'app/ui/apps/moduleTest/widget.html';
        },
        resolve: {
          //Some function to retrieve data
        }
      })
    )
    .state('myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest.wizards',
      modalStateProvider.create({
        animation: true,
        name: 'myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest.wizards',
        url: 'apps/moduleTest/runWizard',
        controllerAs: 'moduleTestWizardCtrl',
        controller: 'ModuleTestWizardCtrl',
        templateUrl: function(){
          return 'app/ui/apps/moduleTest/wizard.html';
        }
        // resolve: {
        //
        // }
      })
    )
})
```

When I'm in state "myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest" Fron ModuleTestCtrl I'm trying to go to the state "myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest.wizards" But I get the error "could not resolve state". How can I import this config module inside my controller in order to navigate to that state?

```
/*jslint node: true */
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');

function ModuleTestCtrl($uibModalInstance, Api, diagnosticsRaw,  myService, $state) {

  this.$uibModalInstance = $uibModalInstance;
  this.Api = Api;
  this.dataRaw = diagnosticsRaw;

  this.parserData = function(indexes) {
      //Some app logic irrelevant
  }

  myService.setPropertyToRun(this.dataRaw);
  myService.setIsPropertyToRun(true);

$state.go('myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest.wizards'); //THIS IS WHERE I HAVE MY PROBLEM

  };
}
```

ModuleTestCtrl.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', 'Api', 'diagnosticsRaw', 'myService', '$state'];
module.exports = ModuleTestCtrl;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you described all parent states of `myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest` and `myApp.dashboard.appArea.moduleTest.wizards` in your angular.config, if not that could be the problem.

Example:
wizards is a child of moduleTest which is a child of appArea which is a child of dashboard which is a child of myApp, you get the point. You first need to have declared all these parent states even though they might not do anything.

More about ui-state at:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views

Comment: thanks for your response. I have all the parent route defined in my app in different folders and files. Maybe I missed a required or an injection? I'm trying to look in that way

Comment: Finally I solved it. All parent routes were defined, but one of the parent states was incorrectly imported in my inner script. As result nested states weren't created. In esence this answer is correct so I will mark it as resolved. Thank you!